# How to run ant script from a shell script?

Tags: shell, ant, scripting, websphere-mq-fte, return-code

I need to run an ant script from a shell script and if the ant script is executed successfully I must get the return code 0 or in case of failure 1. Can anyone tell me how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd ~/yoursourcedir/
ant
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "error happend"
fi
```

`$?` contains the error code of your last command, in this case `ant`.
`-ne 0` means not equal 0, so if any error happened, execute the `echo`.

You can specify the standard paramters to ant, i.e. your buildfile:

```
ant -buildfile build.xml
```

[Summary of ant run options](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)

Comment: Is ant installed correctly? What is shown when you enter `ant` in the command line?